# Is there a time limit to cover an open short position?

Tags: trading, shorting-securities

Let's say there exists a stock X that I believe will soon embark on a general downward trend. I am interested in shorting X and decide to sell some quantity of X.

I see my short position as being a long term view of the stock. This is not generally the case where one holds a short position in a stock.

I understand that if my view of the stock also become the general market view of the same stock that there may be many people wanting to hold short positions of X. How would this affect me?

To summarize:

- Is there a time limit by which I need to cover a short position?
- If the answer to the above is no, what are the downsides to holding a short position for a longer time frame?

Comment: What stock exchange are you looking at.

Comment: If you are not in the USA and short stocks using CFDs you can actually get paid interest when you hold that short position overnight. Also, if more people are shorting the stock as well this can drive the stock price lower thus benefit you.

Comment: @Dheer U.S. and Canadian exchanges

Answer (score 0):

There are situations where you can be forced to cover a position, particular when "Reg SHO" ("regulation sho") is activated.

Reg SHO is intended to make naked short sellers cover their position, it is to prevent abusive failure to delivers, where someone goes short without borrowing someone else's shares. Naked shorting isn't a violation of federal securities laws but it becomes an accounting problem when multiple people have claims to the same underlying assets. (I've seen companies that had 120% of their shares sold short, too funny, FWIW the market was correct as the company was worth nothing.)

You can be naked short without knowing it. So there can be times when you will be forced to cover.

Other people being forced to cover can result in a short squeeze. A risk.

The other downside is that you have to pay interest on your borrowings. You also have to pay the dividends to the owner of the shares, if applicable. In shorter time frames these are negligible, but in longer time frames, such as closer to a year or longer, these really add up. Let alone the costs of the market going in the opposite direction, and the commissions.